Mock the currentTime in useSyncExternalStore
I'm trying to mock the current Time (Temporal.Now.plainDateTimeISO()) with
    vi.setSystemTime(new Date('2024-06-01T11:00:00'));

but every time I run this test the mocked time is ignored.
store:
import { Temporal } from '@js-temporal/polyfill'

const createTimeStore = () => {
  let currentTime = Temporal.Now.plainDateTimeISO()
  const subscribers = new Set<() => void>()

  const subscribe = (callback: () => void) => {
    subscribers.add(callback)
    return () => subscribers.delete(callback)
  }

  const getSnapshot = () => currentTime

  const updateTime = () => {
    currentTime = Temporal.Now.plainDateTimeISO()
    subscribers.forEach((callback) => callback())
    const now = Temporal.Now.plainDateTimeISO()
    const msToNextMinute = (60 - now.second) * 1000 - now.millisecond
    setTimeout(updateTime, msToNextMinute)
  }

  updateTime()

  return {
    subscribe,
    getSnapshot,
  }
}

const timeStore = createTimeStore()

export const useTimeStore = () => {
  const { subscribe, getSnapshot } = timeStore

  return {
    getSnapshot,
    subscribe,
  }
}

test:
test('my test', () => {
    vi.useFakeTimers();
    vi.setSystemTime(new Date('2024-06-01T11:00:00'));
    const { result } = renderHook(() =>
      myHook()
    );

    const time = result.current.getTime();

    expect(time).toBe(11:00);
  });

